# Eyes' positions in an image of a human face?

Tags: c#, image-recognition, emgucv

How can I get the eye(s)' position(s) in an image of a human face ?
For instance, my program searches for eyes and then their positions could be stored in 2D vectors like :

```
Vector2 leftEye = new Vector2(56, 50);
```

I heard about Emgu but I really don't understand how it works with XMLs...

Comment: This question is the very definition of too broad and really not a good fit for stackoverflow format. Please consider reading the help on asking a good question and what questions can be asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using Emgu 3.4.1. The training data xml is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades), and you load that into a `CascadeClassifier` class which can then perform the detection.

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    private const string EYE_DETECTION_XML = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml";
    private const string SAMPLE_IMAGE = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Lewis_Hamilton_2016_Malaysia_2.jpg/330px-Lewis_Hamilton_2016_Malaysia_2.jpg";

    static void Main()
    {
        // download sample photo
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Bitmap image = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(SAMPLE_IMAGE)))
            image = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));

        // convert to Emgu image, convert to grayscale and increase brightness/contrast
        Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte> emguImage = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte>(image);
        var grayScaleImage = emguImage.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        grayScaleImage._EqualizeHist();

        // load eye classifier data
        string eye_classifier_local_xml = @"c:\temp\haarcascade_eye.xml";
        client.DownloadFile(@EYE_DETECTION_XML, eye_classifier_local_xml);        
        CascadeClassifier eyeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(eye_classifier_local_xml);

        // perform detection which will return rectangles of eye positions
        var eyes = eyeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayScaleImage, 1.1, 4);

        // draw those rectangles on original image
        foreach (Rectangle eye in eyes)
            emguImage.Draw(eye, new Bgr(255, 0, 0), 3);

        // save image and show it
        string output_image_location = @"c:\temp\output.png";        
        emguImage.ToBitmap().Save(output_image_location, ImageFormat.Png);
        Process.Start(output_image_location);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot YOU're a nice person :)